# How do I force keyboard focus for a Modal Window without Title Bar

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I want to run a simple dialog similar to Finder Go To Folder.

I have used a NSPanel made this Document Modal and run with runModal.
This works, but displays a title.

If I turn off the Title Bar (in IB) the buttons work, but the NSTextField does not get keyboard focus.
I have tried lots of techniques to make it firstResponder or set as key, setBecomesKeyOnlyIfNeeded:NO but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to subclass `NSWindow`, override `- (BOOL)canBecomeKeyWindow` and return `YES`.

By default, borderless windows cannot become the key window.

Comment: Thanks, this worked but it wasn't obvious from the documentation.
I had been trying makeKeyWindow (which is documented) but kept getting an error instance method not found